# Why does $X_0\times S^1\simeq X-X_0$?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, riemannian-geometry, differential-topology

Let $X$ be an $n$-dimensional connected smooth manifold, and let $X_0$ be an embedded $(n-2)$-dimensional compact submanifold of $X$ with the trivial normal bundle. How do we get inclusion?

$$X_0\times S^1\hookrightarrow X-X_0$$

and show that it is actually a homotopy equivalence?

My thought is that we remove a small neighborhood of $X_0$ containing $X_0$ to get the inclusion because the left part can deform to $X_0\times S^1$. But I'm confused about whether it is right.

Could you please give me some help with the details? Thanks

Comment: It generally will not be a homotopy-equivalence, but the inclusion comes from the tubular neighbourhood theorem.  You considering the unit normal bundle in the tubular neighbourhood.

Comment: Is my idea right?@RyanBudney

Comment: @JohnDasara As written, not really, since (as Ryan points out) $X - X_0$ doesn't necessarily deform to $X\times S^1$. But it will be true after you replace $X$ by a (sufficiently small) tubular neighborhood of $X_0$ inside $X$.

Answer (score 2):

There is no hope for such a homotopy equivalence.  As an example, suppose that $X = S^2$ is the two sphere and suppose that $x_0 \in X$ is a single point. So $x_0$ is a zero-dimensional ($0 = 2 - 2$) submanifold.  Thus $x_0 \times S^1$ is a circle and not homotopy equivalent to $X - x_0$, a plane.